# Getting jquery script to delete itself after executing

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am a rookie web developer with a website containing 3 different items, each with its individual "contact me" button. When the button is pressed for the first time, the page scrolls down to display the form.

My problem is the event fires once pr button, instead of once in total. I want the script to fire once regardless of which button is pressed, then the script should delete itself or stop further executions.

I just don't see where this script fails. Please enlighten me :)

Below is a very simplified proof of concept with a jsfiddle attached.

https://jsfiddle.net/8wegb32s/

```css
#megaspacer {
  height: 1000px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
<input form="form" class="orderbutton" type="radio" id="1" name="product" value="Value1" />
<input form="form" class="orderbutton" type="radio" id="2" name="product" value="Value2" />
<input form="form" class="orderbutton" type="radio" id="3" name="product" value="Value3" />
<div id="megaspacer">
  <!--Give me som space -->
</div>
<form id="anchor">
  <input type="text" name="name" id="name" class="form-control text-dark" placeholder="Name*">
</form>
<script id="runonce">
  $(".orderbutton").one("click", function() {
    $('html, body').animate({
      scrollTop: $("#anchor").offset().top
    }, 2000);
    $("script").remove("#runonce");
  });
</script>
```

Solved in https://jsfiddle.net/gaby/g7bw1mkn/10/

Comment: Deleting a `<script>` tag doesn't make the code, that was started inside, stop.

Comment: @ths Don't make edits that changes how the code works.

Comment: @gre_gor did it change the code when i edited ? No.

Comment: Did you check what the code is doing? You removed the script tag with the id "runonce", which the code removes.

Comment: @gre_gor the script was moved to the `JS` tab of `SO`'s `JS Snippets`. I saw the issue, edited the question while keeping that script tag in its original place while having a runnable snippet. Thanks for the catch though, have a nice day.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do not remove the script. Just remove the event handler.

```js
$(".orderbutton").on("click", function() {
  $('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: $("#anchor").offset().top
  }, 2000);
  
  $(".orderbutton").off('click');
});
```

If you bind additional handlers on the same buttons, though, you will have to use a named function which is required when you want to remove only that.

```
function orderButtonClickHandler(){
  $('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: $("#anchor").offset().top
  }, 2000);
  
  $(".orderbutton").off('click',orderButtonClickHandler);
}
$(".orderbutton").on("click", orderButtonClickHandler);
```

---

Or you can use the delegated form, where you bind the event handler to an ancestor of the buttons. This way, since it is only bound to a single element, it will stop functioning after the first use, as expected.

```js
$("body").one("click", ".orderbutton", function() {
  $('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: $("#anchor").offset().top
  }, 2000);
});
```

Comment: This works, but that also stops the button from applying some css colors to the selected item.

Fiddle with old script, divs change color depending on selected object.
https://jsfiddle.net/d063p4gf/

Fiddle with new script, only changes once.
https://jsfiddle.net/d063p4gf/1/

Comment: @PibbZ if you bind additional click handlers on the same element, then you will need to use a named function, so that you can remove only that one when you want. See https://jsfiddle.net/gaby/g7bw1mkn/10/

Comment: Aah, this makes sense! Thanks a LOT for taking the time to make a fiddle aswell :)